# How to catch status = cancelled in axios?

Tags: ajax, rest, express, redux, axios

I am currently running 2 servers:

1. To serve the view using react which retrieves data from REST API built with express.
2. To provide the REST API for the view.

Below is my action for logging a user in:

```
// Redux Action
export function loginUser(creds, role) {

  return dispatch => {
    // We dispatch requestLogin to kickoff the call to the API
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds));

    return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/login/${role}`, creds).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);

        if(response.status === 200) {
          // If login was successful, set the token in local storage
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data);

          // Dispatch the success action
          dispatch(receiveLogin(response));

          return response;
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        // If there was a problem, we want to
        // dispatch the error condition
        dispatch(loginError(err.data));

        return err;
      });
  };
}
```

I purposely disconnected my database to catch errors and see what happens. So, this is what I can see in the terminal:

```
12:49:24 Project-0 Server is listening at port 3000
12:49:24 Project-0 Mongoose disconnected
12:49:24 Project-0 Mongoose connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.116:27017
12:49:34 Project-0 Wed, 13 Apr 2016 07:19:34 GMT express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead at app/index.js:61:7
12:49:34 Project-0 OPTIONS /login/admin Wed, 13 Apr 2016 07:19:34 GMT ::ffff:192.168.1.134 200 5.894
12:49:35 Project-0 POST /login/admin Wed, 13 Apr 2016 07:19:35 GMT ::ffff:192.168.1.134 - -
```

Now, when I submit the login form, **status goes from pending to cancelled**.

**How can we catch this status using axios or do we have to write a mechanism for this in express itself?**

[Axios 0.10.0](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

**Note:** I couldn't tag axios as the tag doesn't exist and I can't create a new one.

Comment: hi
where do you exactly see status (pending,cancelled) now? what do these statuses mean in your case? why do you get it cancelled? from your question it is hard to uncerstand

Comment: @AlexBuduguru I am not sure if it's fixed in the newer versions of Axios. I have already mentioned it occurs in version Axios 0.10.0. I see the status in google chrome's network tab. I have already explained that I disconnect the app from database. Hence, after sending a request and waiting for a while, the status changes to cancelled.

Comment: I think I do not understand exactly what is the purpose of catching status type and what problem you are trying to solve. Could you elaborate more? The problem is that the request becomes canceled and you do not understand why it happens, right?

Comment: See we catch status type so that we can log the error/success messages. If the status is successful then we usually play around with the data. If status type is cancelled or failed, we need to log this for debugging or display to the that something didn't go well.. And hence I wanna catch the status type cancelled so that I can log a nessage. But I can't catch it unfortunately.

Comment: you can just put console.log(err) in your catch statement - this will log unsuccessful response. Why would you need anything else?

.catch(err => { console.log(err)});

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use axios.isCancel()

```
.catch(err => { 
      if(axios.isCancel(err)) {
        // do something
      }
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually catch errors(unsuccessful responses) in catch statement. You can for example log it to console like this:

```js
.catch(err => {
        // If there was a problem, we want to
        // dispatch the error condition
        dispatch(loginError(err.data));
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I submit the login form, status goes from pending to cancelled.

This happens because you set the timeout in axios. Of course when the request **times out**, axios cancels the request. By default timeout is `0`, meaning axios will never timeout if a request is *Never Ending*.

> How can we catch this status using axios or do we have to write a mechanism for this in express itself?

You can detect an error thrown by axios as a result of it being cancelled.

1. As @Rafal has Mentioned:

   ```js
   .catch(error => { 
       if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
           // Your logic here
       }
   }
   )
   ```
2. `error.code`:

   ```js
   .catch(error => { 
       if(error?.code === "ERR_CANCELED") {
           // do something
       }
   }
   )
   ```
3. `error.name`:

   ```js
   .catch(error => { 
       if(error?.name === "CanceledError") {
           // request was cancelled..do something
       }
   }
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did following things to resolve the issue.

1. Upgrade the axios version to v0.22.0 because this supports the AbortControlled.
2. Create a utility function to pass a abort signal

```
export const newAbortSignal = (timeoutMs: number) => {
  if (process.browser) { 
   // this check is required if you are using next.js as AbortController is only available on client side browser env.

    const abortController = new AbortController()
    setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), timeoutMs || 0)

    return abortController.signal
  }
}
```

3. Pass the signal in axios get config

```
const abortSignal = newAbortSignal(500)

  axios.get(`endpoint-name`, {
      signal: abortSignal
    })
```

for more info checkout the docs
https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation